# Is ECC feature in DDR realized with using Hamming code technique?

Tags: ddr, ecc

The fundamental formula for a Hamming coding is as below:

> 2^k≥n+k+1
>
> Where k = # of parity bits and n = data bits

In a DDR system with ECC feature, every data byte will generate an additional ECC bit which makes a byte data 9 bits long.

However, if simply applying the Hamming code formula here, 8 bits of data will require 4 parity bits which will make the encoded data 12 bits long.

In this case, how can the DDR ECC feature be realized with the Hamming coding scheme?

Comment: It's trivial to understand by using a venn diagram or a concept related to packing spheres, in this case.

Answer (score 8):

The ECC is not performed on an individual byte basis.

Usually, 8 bytes are combined with one parity bit per byte. Giving a total of 72 bits.

Since only 7 parity bits are needed to correct single-bit errors and 8 are available the extra bit can be used to detect double bit errors, although not correct the error.

[Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code)

[Hamming Codes With Additional Parity](https://www.liquisearch.com/hamming_code/hamming_codes_with_additional_parity_secded)

Comment: So every additional bit generated from a byte data is simply a parity result from that particular 8 bits data?

Comment: @Learner - no. The parity bits have to come from a combination of bits among multiple bytes.

Comment: Looking at the algorithm table from the Wikipedia, supposed 64 bits data only require 7 parity bits. Technically, can i say that the parity #8 in a DDR symbol is redundant?

Comment: @Learner - it adds the capability of detecting double-bit errors.

Answer (score 6):

DDR4 is not byte accessable. Each address has 64 bits or 8 bytes. The ECC makes each symbol 72 bits wide.

Comment: that's mean the 2^k≥n+k+1 formula still valid for this? 2^8 >= 64+8+1

Comment: @Learner No, `2^7 ≥ 64+7+1`. When ECC is used for DDR RAM, there are usually a multiple of 9 chips (usually 9 chips with 8 bits per chip). Thus, there are 72 bits available: 64 bits for the data, 7 bits for the Hamming code and 1 bit which is often used as a parity bit to detect double bit errors.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, ECC with DDRam only can correct single bit errors.

Comment: That's true for the usual SECDED scheme but there are others.